# Countability with Infinite Sets- Proofs Question

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory, cardinals

Here's my question: **Let  `A ⊆ ℝ` be a countable set. Prove that  `ℝ \ A` is uncountable.**

In class, we just learned about cardinality, power sets, and injections, surjections, and bijections. 
So I know that a set is countable if it has the same cardinality as the natural numbers `N`. I also know that the set `R` is uncountable. Usually if wanting to prove that `R` is uncountable, it is sufficient to prove that `(0,1)` is uncountable and does not have the same cardinality as the natural number `N`. So, I know I have to proceed by contradiction.

I feel like I have the information, but I do not know where to start. Do I prove by contradiction that a bijection from `N` to `R\A` cannot exist. If yes, how do I do so?

My attempt was: 
Let `a ∈ N` and `b ∈ R\A`. So, my plan is to prove surjectiviy and injectivity of a function `f: N → R\A`. Now, proving surjectivity, I know that if `b ∈ R\A`, there must be `a ∈ N`.

Am I going on the right track? Where do I go from here? How do I use the information given to me in the question? Is there perhaps bigger concepts I am missing?

Can someone please help me with this or show me how they would prove this?

Comment: No, you are bot going on the right track. For instance, the paragraph with your attempt makes no sense. You talk of injectivity and surjectivity. Of what?

Comment: If it were otherwise, $\mathbb{R} - A$ would be (at most) countable. To understand the cardinality of two at-most countable sets, consider arranging their elements in sequences $\{a_n\}$ and $\{b_n\}$; can we create a new sequence $\{c_n\}$ such that every $a_n$ or $b_n$ is $c_m$ for some $m$? If so, then the union of the two sets $A$ and $\mathbb{R}- A$ can be counted (since all their elements can be arranged in a sequence). For safety's sake: you should get that the union of these (any two!) countable sets is countable. Then apply that to $A$ and $\mathbb{R} - A$.

Comment: Also, @AndrésE.Caicedo is not incorrect in saying that your attempt is mistaken. If you proved injectivity and surjectivity of a function from $A$ to $\mathbb{R} - A$, then you would prove a bijection; but $A$ is countable, and $\mathbb{R} - A$ is supposed to be uncountable, so you would have a bijection between a countable and uncountable set, which is not possible.

Comment: @Chris thanks for the clear explanation. It really helps as it's my first time working with proofs and working with discrete math and high school does not really prepare you for this kind of thinking. I edited my question. I am instead proving bijection from `N` to `R\A` cannot exist.

Comment: As currently worded, you say "my plan is to prove surjectivity and injectivity of a function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R} - A$", and a surjective and injective function *would* be a bijection. And you're quite welcome :)

Comment: Thank you everyone and @Chris for your help!  :D I will think about this problem a bit more. I'll be back if I have any more questions.

Comment: If A and R - A are countable, then R is countabl4 which it is not by Cantor's theorem.